# Transactional Fact Table

Tags: powerbi, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

I have Accounting fact table and all financial transactions are posted in it. For One attribute, source system can have three type of values (General Ledger/Customer Account/Limit ).These are three separate dimensions in the model. For Fact table, should I store this attribute in one or multiple columns. Multiple columns will be easier to link with each dimension table as compared to single. But later if new products introduced, fact table need to changed to address this.

Comment: Are the other dimensions associated to the fact the same regardless of the source type? If they are then it makes sense to have a single fact table with 1 Dimension referencing the Source. If the fact table structure differs depending on source then it makes more sense to create a fact table per source and then (if appropriate) combine the common dimensions into a single consolidated fact table. Have a look at this: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/supertype-subtype-heterogeneous/